# Exclude a list of files from a dir command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, directory, findstr

I need to make a list of files using dir that does not include certain files listed in a .txt file. I tried doing something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
dir %ProjectDir%\*.ts /b /s | findstr /v /f:listFiles.txt > Files.txt
```

**Edit**: This sort of works but only one file name gets added to the text file.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir %ProjectDir%TypeScript\*.ts /b /s') 
do (
  find /i "%%a" < strictFiles.txt > nul || echo.%%a > tsFiles.txt
)
```

Comment: Try using the correct option. `/f` provides a list of files for `findstr` to examine for the strings. If you use `/g` then it will read your file and match against the text in the file.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I just get a blank text file.

Comment: Please show us a sample of your `listfiles.txt`